# A small note AFTER a normal sized note in a chord. How do I play it?

Tags: notation

[image: Two measures from "Concentrating" by Willie "Lion" Smith]

What are these notes called? It doesn't look like a regular appoggiatura notation, the tiny note is placed after the main one. How should I be playing them?

Willie "Lion" Smith - Concentrating

Comment: What piece is this?  It looks like a piano-conductor score for a Broadway show or similar.

Comment: Willie "Lion" Smith - Concentratin

Comment: What edition or arrangement is the image from?

Comment: Based on the placement of the tiny notes, they seem held or representing emphasis. Note that they are placed *only* right next to accented notes - maybe they're an inner melody?

Comment: Are these kinds of notes found throughout the arrangement, or only in these two measures?

Comment: @Aaron 4 measures repeated twice, so only one section of the solo

Comment: Does the rest of the arrangement have the same kind of low-high low-high chordal left hand?

Comment: I agree with Dekkadeci.  It is just drawing your attention to the melodic line.  Try to bring that line out amid the general activity around it.

Comment: @Aaron each section is different from one another
What about the different duration? quarters, halves, wholes

Comment: It just means you would play, say, the whole note for the entire measure, and not play the other chords indicated. However, the presence of these kinds of notations elsewhere in the arrangement could matter. @Dekkadeci's suggestion is plausible as well and, if correct, would likely be explained in the preface to the collection containing the transcription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are alternative performance options to simplify the arrangement. The general term is **[ossia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossia)**.

It is also possible that they represent alternative ways that Willie "The Lion" Smith performed the piece.

Comment: For some reasons, I was thinking it was a "reversed Appoggiatura".

Answer (score 0):

There's a little internal melody, indicated by the accents on E, D and C♯ in the tenor register.

It would be difficult for a pianist to 'bring out' that melody within the stride texture. This notation may be suggesting that he at least tries! But I think it's more likely this piano part is from an arrangement including more instruments.  The cue notes tell us that e.g. a trombone will play those notes.

Where did you find it?

Comment: a transcription of Willie "Lion" Smith's solo  ( Leo Feist, 1939)